# How do I wash my kids' hair without them screaming their lungs out?

Tags: hygiene, fears

My kids are both under six years of age.
Occasionally, when they are really dirty and sweaty,
I need to wash their hair with shampoo.
The trouble starts when I try to wash the shampoo out of their hair,
by using a big scoop to pour water over their hair.
Inevitably, some water gets into their eyes,
and they start screaming as if it is the end of the world.
I am able to use a small towel to wipe the water out of their eyes
but only after some water has already gotten in their eyes
and the screaming has begun.

How can I wash my kids' hair without traumatizing them?

Comment: If the answer marked as duplicate doesn't address your concerns, please post a question with an explanation of why the answers to the duplicate were unhelpful. Thanks!